# Webpack// Chunk error, precompiling assets failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, npm, webpack

I've been through every suggestion I can find throughout Google and StackOverflow, and still can't come up with a solution. I've been fighting this all day, and not sure where to go.

Trying to host an app on heroku - I'm getting this error:

> Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by instanceof Entrypoint instead
> remote:            at Chunk.get (/tmp/build_957e6b3a/node_modules/webpack/lib/Chunk.js:866:9)
> remote:            at /tmp/build_957e6b3a/node_modules/@rails/webpacker/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:176:48
> remote:            at Array.forEach ()
> remote:            at /tmp/build_957e6b3a/node_modules/@rails/webpacker/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:171:18
> remote:            at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/tmp/build_957e6b3a/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :7:1)
> remote:            at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/tmp/build_957e6b3a/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
> remote:            at Compilation.seal (/tmp/build_957e6b3a/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1342:27)
> remote:            at compilation.finish.err (/tmp/build_957e6b3a/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:675:18)
> remote:            at hooks.finishModules.callAsync.err (/tmp/build_957e6b3a/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1261:4)
> remote:            at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/tmp/build_957e6b3a/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :24:1)
> remote:            at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/tmp/build_957e6b3a/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
> remote:            at Compilation.finish (/tmp/build_957e6b3a/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1253:28)
> remote:            at hooks.make.callAsync.err (/tmp/build_957e6b3a/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:672:17)
> remote:            at _err0 (eval at create (/tmp/build_957e6b3a/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :11:1)
> remote:            at _addModuleChain (/tmp/build_957e6b3a/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1185:12)
> remote:            at processModuleDependencies.err (/tmp/build_957e6b3a/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1097:9)
> remote:            at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)

My package.json looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^3.2.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "^15.3.0",
    "react-calendar": "^3.2.1",
    "react-datetime": "^3.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.0",
    "react-moment": "^1.0.0",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "webpack": "webpack --watch --mode=development",
    "postinstall": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.17.0",
    "npm": "6.4.1"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.1",
    "webpack": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

I have tried, I think, every combination of webpack/webpack-cli/mini-css-extract plugin/extract-text-webpack-plugin. I've put them in dependencies, and also in devDependencies. Deleting node_modules and package-json.lock in between every attempt. I've tried git push -f heroku. I have been fighting this literally all weekend and have gotten nowhere.

Does anybody know what the problem is? And does anyone have any suggestions?